# Advantages of low voltage steppers

Tags: voltage, stepper-motor

Many vendors now offer low-voltage stepper motors, e.g. 2 V or even 1.8 V.
What are the advantages and disadvantages of such motors relative to 12 V or 24 V motors?

Comment: advantages and disadvantages depend on the application

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that you can overcome the inductance of the coil to a large degree by powering a low voltage motor coil with a **chopped** current-controlled PWM waveform of much higher than rated peak voltage. When the current rises to the rated value, the controller shuts the MOSFET switch off and the current starts to decay. Then the process repeats, at many kHz.

If you make the stepper capable of handling continuous (say) 12V it will be very slow, which is undesirable in many applications. Especially where you want to maintain torque at relatively high RPM (such as in modern 3D printers).

The power consumption (and thus the current draw from, say, a 12V supply) is similar in either case, all other things being equal. The motor controller essentially acts as a buck switchmode converter reducing the higher voltage to the motor rated voltage, and using the motor inductance as the inductor.

One disadvantage is that if the motor controller fails 'on' it will probably fry the motor.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the new low voltage stepper motor is easy interface with modern low voltage computer equipment. This can mean less PCB real estate. The drawback comes at higher powers where the current draw can cause problems like transient voltage drops at turn on and transient overshoots at turn off. Remember that a 2.4 VDC stepper motor all things being equal will pull 10 times the current of the standard 24VDC unit.